# Spring Boot - Request method 'POST' not supported (Method not allowed)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, post

As I followed this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/ after a while I came to a dead end. I tried to figure out what the problem is for some hours now. I hope you can help me.

When I submit my form, I get this error-message:

```
 There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
 Request method 'POST' not supported
```

My App (App.java):

```
package de.poc.logging.main;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }
}
```

My Controller (InformationController.java):

```
package de.poc.logging.main;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/info")
public class InformationController {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
  public String infoForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("information", new Information());
    return "infoForm.html";
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
  public String infoSubmit(@ModelAttribute Information information) {
    return "infoResult.html";
  }
}
```

I created an additional class for security (WebSecurityConf.java):

```
package de.poc.logging.main.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.headers()
        .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
        .httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable();
    http.csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

And I have following two HTML-Files:

infoForm.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/info}" th:object="${information}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}"/></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset"/></p>
        <!--<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>-->
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

infoResult.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Result</h1>
<p th:text="'id: ' + ${information.id}"/>
<p th:text="'content: ' + ${information.content}"/>
<a href="/info">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit (additional information):
my Information.java:

```
package de.poc.logging.main;

public class Information {
  private long id;
  private String content;

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getContent() {
    return content;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
  }

}
```

my pom-dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I'm using Java 1.8u121 (jdk).

Edit2:
I tried 3 different versions of spring boot now.
Also I downloaded the project from here: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-handling-form-submission and added spring boot via pom.xml.
The downloaded project does not work for me.

I'm getting really frustrated.

Comment: does it work if you remove security configuration?

Comment: No, I fear that does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. My pom.xml was wrong.
The right one looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-handling-form-submission</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Q: So what did you change in your pom.xml to make it work?

Comment: I had to add spring boot starter as a parent to the project.

Answer (score 2):

I copied your exact same classes except the web security class and tried to run. The post method is working for me. The only change I made was returning file names without the `.html` extension.

My controller class looks like this

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import com.example.models.Information;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/info")
public class InformationController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
    public String infoForm(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("information", new Information());
        return "infoForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
    public String infoSubmit(@ModelAttribute Information information) {
        return "infoResult";
    }
}
```

Comment: If I remove the .html-extention, the form cannot even be called. I could not figure out why yet. (There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available) - I've added some additional information to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with @RequestParam instead of @ModelAttribute?

Something like this..

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
public String infoSubmit(@RequestParam("info") Information information) {
        return "infoResult.html";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried it, but I get an error: "Required Information parameter 'information' is not present"